# Does MariaDB support lower_case_table_names=0 in windows?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently upgrade mysql5.6x to mariaDB v10, both included with XAMPP. However, the lower_case_table_names = 0 does not work in mariaDB in windows. Lower_case_table_names = 1 and 2 works fine but not 0. Previously it work fine in mysql. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB documentation on [identifier case sensitivity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-case-sensitivity/) says:

> The lower_case_table_names server system variable plays a key role. It
>   determines whether table names, aliases and database names are
>   compared in a case-sensitive manner. If set to 0 (the default on
>   Unix-based systems), table names and aliases and database names are
>   compared in a case-sensitive manner. If set to 1 (the default on
>   Windows), names are stored in lowercase and not compared in a
>   case-sensitive manner. If set to 2 (the default on Mac OS X), names
>   are stored as declared, but compared in lowercase.
>
> **It is thus possible to make Unix-based systems behave like Windows and
>   ignore case-sensitivity, but the reverse is not true, as the
>   underlying Windows filesystem can not support this.**

(Highlighting is mine)

The highlighted sentence implies that you cannot set lower_case_table_names to 0 in Windows.

Comment: I saw that article too but it is a bumper. The lower_case_table_names=0 was great in mysql5.6x, it doesn't make sense they say windows filesystem can not support this. Going back to mysql then.

Comment: Actually, they are right to say that. In windows file paths are not case sensitive and you can get into trouble if you use case sensitive identifier setting on windows.

Comment: Since MySQL and MariaDB _both_ depend on filenames, they are _both_ subject to the OS limitations.  @vincenttan -- what makes you think that MySQL will _act_ differently?

Comment: I have no idea. The fact is i was able to use lower_case_table = 0 in windows in earlier version of mysql. Now it seem that feature is gone or fixed (the way it should be i guess). I needed it for concrete5. 
http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/mysql-database-case-insensitivity 
Anyway, i has switched to linux mint now. All is good. Thanks

Comment: The highlighted statement is not accurate.  NTFS can have posix semantics w.r.t case-sensitivity (i.e store files 'a' and 'A' in the same directory), but this could break application which  usually assume case-insensitivity. Also NTFS is *case-preserving*, so the reason of lowercasing names is completely beyond me.  Yet actually, in SQL identifiers are case-insensitive, it is the current default Unix behavior is, strictly speaking, a bug  (or a feature, which is not likely to be fixed)

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub Mysql would have to detect what file system it is installed on (ntfs vs fatNN) and decide whether that particular version supports case sensitive file names. Well, it is a lot simpler not to use case sensitive file names on windows than doing this. Not to mention that the default way of windows api accessing the file system is case insensitive, but case preserving (it is not ntfs that is case preserving, it is the windows api), and case sensitive access through the api is limited, it is again simpler for mysql / mariadb to have case insensitive file names on windows.

Comment: Mariadb documentstion could have explained this in a very detsiled manner, but I do not think this is wholly relevant to the subject, so the rationale is simplified. I can live with that.

Comment: @Shadow : MySQL actually does this case sensitivity check : https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/mysqld.cc#L8222 . Not on Windows specifically, but everywhere. Of course it does not use any "posix semantics". I agree btw that handling Windows as case-insensitive is easier because most tools assume that.